# How to make it only read ONE word in C++

Tags: c++

Here's my code:

```
char *reason = strtok(NULL, "\n");
std::string kickreason = "No reason";
if(reason)
kickreason = reason;
```

How do I make the "kickreason" only read 1 word? So if the user types in "haha lol XD" it will only read "haha"?

Comment: Please choose a language, and remove all the chatter from the question.

Comment: *if the guy types in "haha lol XD"*  ....then you should probably beat the crap out of him.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`stringstream::operator>>(string)`? that's where you need to look at.

like this:

```
istringstream str("no reason");
string oneword = "";
str >> oneword;
```

Comment: I tried to be a little too clever. Wrong thing.. wait let me change.

Answer (score 2):

Put the string in a [`std::istringstream`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istringstream) and use the normal input operator `>>`:

```
std::istringstream iss("haha lol XD");
std::string word;

iss >> word;

std::cout << "First word is \"" << word << "\"\n";
```

Comment: You might want to also mention `std::string::substr` and `std::string::find`...

Answer (score 0):

how about using strtok()

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <iostream>

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    char sentence[] = "haha lol XD";  
    char * word;
    std::cout << "Your sentence: " << sentence << std::endl;
    word = strtok (sentence," ");
    std::cout << "First word: " << word << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

The output is

```
Your sentence: haha lol XD
First word: haha
```